# How do I import an HTML template into a Vue.js project?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to import a template that I [downloaded off the internet](https://colorlib.com/wp/template/fancy/) into my vue project. The template has its own HTML, CSS, and Javascript files. How do I use vue-router to access the `index.html` that is in that project without converting them into vue components?

I'm not sure if `v-html` is the way to go since I have to import and then convert the HTML into a huge string.

I'm doing this for my landing page so it doesn't need to access Vuex and all the other complexities. I just need it to be displayed as a normal HTML.

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZHqQ.jpg)

Comment: "I just need it to be displayed as a normal HTML." - then why you are even using VueJS ?

Comment: @BelminBedak as I said, it's only for the landing page. I have the application run with VueJS but I'd like a pretty landing page that I can download off the internet that doesn't need to do anything other than look nice and link to the login page

Comment: Still, why It needs to be imported in your Vue application If It's completely decoupled from your Vue application ? 
If you really want to do It like that, then create new component, pull the HTML from your landing page there, and point route to that component.

Comment: What you *can* do is, serve the landing page off the root of your webapp, and serve vue's dist folder from a subfolder. For example, your landing is served from abc.com/index.html and your vue app is served from abc.com/app/index.html, and the you can use a simple anchor to send the user to the vue dist folder.

Comment: @Shuvojit how do I do what you suggested?

Comment: [Here is my folder structure](https://imgur.com/a/my29YBN). The "Landing" folder in public/ is the folder that contains the HTML CSS and Javascript for the landing page I want to add

Comment: Set vue's dist folder to public/app, then when finally deploying set webapp root to public. And make sure the index.html inside public is the one of the landing template you downloaded. So, now, when user will go to /, your downloaded landing will be shown, but when they go to /app, vue's build folder's index.html will be returned, thus taking him to the vue app.

Comment: THANK YOU @Shuvojit!!! Your suggestion worked like a charm.

Comment: Posting this as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, serve the landing page off the root of your webapp, and serve vue's dist folder from a subfolder.

For example, your landing is served from abc.com/index.html and your vue app is served from abc.com/app/index.html, and the you can use a simple anchor to send the user to the vue dist folder.

The actionable steps would be - 
1. Set vue's dist folder to public/app
2. When finally deploying, set webapp root to public and make sure the index.html inside public is the one of the landing template you downloaded.

So, now, when user will go to /, your downloaded landing will be shown, but when they go to /app, vue's build folder's index.html will be returned, thus taking him to the vue app.